# object_id of keys (and some other objects) are always the same. Why is that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

In every Ruby program `Symbol` :x (where x is any characters sequence allowed to be used as a name for a `Symbol`) has the same `object_id`.

The same thing is with false/true/nil.

I wonder - why is that? Does it mean that every time Ruby initialise all these objects before code is executed (like false/true/nil)? <--- **Already answered here: [How does object_id assignment work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430280/how-does-object-id-assignment-work)**

And what about `Symbols`? Are these initialised also? A millions of possible combinations? How is it possible that their .object_id are the same between programs.

Comment: I think a better question would be. "What is the method used by Ruby to compute the `object_id` of an object?" needless to say that if every time you run Ruby the `object_id` of an specific object changes, it's because something is changing. Because nothing changed you can expect the same object_id  in the same platform for an specific object.

Comment: I didn't approach problem from this point of view! Nice tip :)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430280/how-does-object-id-assignment-work

Comment: @architgupta answers don't say anything about symbols. I found there answer only to the first part of my question

Comment: I am digging deeper :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So i searched over the internet and found out this article http://threebrothers.org/brendan/blog/memory-and-ruby-symbols/ . I come to know that ruby process maintains a [symbol table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_table) which has one entry per symbol as long as the process exists, so whenever a new symbol is created ruby do a search in that symbol table and if not exists it creates a new one to the last entry just like the entries in database tables.

More sources that can help:

[Id2sym & symbol.object_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21073919/id2sym-symbol-object-id)

Comment: Want to note post is a bit outdated about garbage collector in Ruby. Actually GC for symbols exists (post tells it doesn't): http://www.sitepoint.com/symbol-gc-ruby-2-2/

Comment: added a new source that can help

Answer (score -1):

**From the `"The Book Of Ruby"`**

> A symbol is, in fact, a pointer into the symbol table. The symbol
>   table is Ruby’s internal list of known identifiers – such as variable
>   and method names.

A Symbol is efficient as keys, as there can't be instances of it. It's like a constant.

It's also worth noting that every whole number will have same `object_id` as opposed to types like String. `Boolean`, `FixNum`, `nil` have the same `object_id`

```
"Iamnotefficentasakey".object_id #=> Different here 
"Iamnotefficentasakey".object_id #=> Different here
:iam.object_id #=> Same here
:iam.object_id #=> Same here
```

Comment: `It's also worth noting that every whole number will have same object_id as opposed to other data types.` - that's false. False/True/Nil have always the same id